# Pytorch sum over a list of tensors along an axis

Tags: pytorch

I have a list of tensors of the same shape. 
I would like to sum the entire list of tensors along an axis.
Does `torch.cumsum` perform this op along a dim?
If so it requires the list to be converted to a single tensor and summed over?

Comment: What's your accurate requirements? And what output do you want?

Answer (score 17):

you don't need `cumsum`, `sum` is your friend
and yes you should first convert them into a single tensor with `stack` or `cat` based on your needs, something like this:

```
import torch
my_list = [torch.randn(3, 5), torch.randn(3, 5)]
result = torch.stack(my_list, dim=0).sum(dim=0).sum(dim=0)
print(result.shape) #torch.Size([5])
```

Comment: Would have liked to see a builtin function/operator for this.